# Windows Phone POST method WebClient class

Tags: windows-phone-7, post, webclient

I am new to this forum as well as Windows Phone Development. I am currently developing an app in which I am working with a Web-Service and I need to make a POST request to a web service. 
I am trying to accomplish a user login functionality here for which,
-> http://abc.com/login (URI)
-> (PARAMETERS) 
apikey: 32 byte long alpha-numeric
username: 3-15 characters
password: 3-15 characters

So for this I am trying to use WebClient class' UploadStringSync method in order to POST the data. My code is as follows.

```
WebClient wc1 = new WebClient();
wc1.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://abc.com/login"),"POST","?apikey=" + Apikey + "&username=username&password=password");
wc1.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc1_UploadStringCompleted);

void wc1_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
          MessageBox.Show(e.Result); 
}
```

Execution stops here at MessageBox line and throws message saying 'The remote server returned an error: NotFound.'

Is there any problem with the way I am passing the parameters? I tried to search for the working implementation everywhere but was unable to find it.

Can anybody help me with this? This is a starting point of my project and really need help on this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something with your `Url`. Can you try add `www` and absolute `UriKind`: `new Uri("http://WWW.abc.com/login", UriKind.Absolute)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    public void Post(string address, string parameters, Action<string> onResponseGot)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(address);
        HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        r.Method = "POST";


        r.BeginGetRequestStream(delegate(IAsyncResult req)
            {
                var outStream = r.EndGetRequestStream(req);

                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(outStream))
                    w.Write(parameters);

                r.BeginGetResponse(delegate(IAsyncResult result)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)r.EndGetResponse(result);

                            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                                {
                                    onResponseGot(reader.ReadToEnd());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            onResponseGot(null);
                        }

                    }, null);

            }, null);
    }
```

Comment: What does the Action<string> onResponseGot parameter needs to be?

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked

```
 WebClient web = new WebClient();
 web.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 web.UploadStringAsync((new Uri("http://www.something.com/?page=something")), "POST", string.Format("v1=onevalue&v2=anothervalue"));
 web.UploadStringCompleted += web_UploadStringCompleted;
```

and after upload is complete to get the html i used htmlagilitypack, you can just get the whole html using e.Result

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(e.Result);
 HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body//table");
 MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
```